# Listbox displayed sequence with Find method of Range

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I am using the following to populate a listbox on a userform. I am finding that the first matching value found always ends up shown as the last value displayed in the listbox. The other found values are displayed in the listbox in the sequence in which they are found. How can I get the first found value to appear at the start of the list?

```
With Sheet8.Range("B6:B99999")
    Set rngFind = .Find(tbCustSearch.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    '   If value found then set a variable for the address
    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        strFirstFind = rngFind.Address
        '   Add the values to the listbox
        Do
            If rngFind.Row > 1 Then
                lbCustSearch.AddItem rngFind.Offset(0, -1)
                lbCustSearch.List(lbCustSearch.ListCount - 1, 1) = rngFind.Value
                lbCustSearch.List(lbCustSearch.ListCount - 1, 2) = rngFind.Offset(0, 1)
                lbCustSearch.List(lbCustSearch.ListCount - 1, 3) = rngFind.Offset(0, 2)
                lbCustSearch.List(lbCustSearch.ListCount - 1, 4) = rngFind.Offset(0, 3)
                lbCustSearch.List(lbCustSearch.ListCount - 1, 5) = rngFind.Offset(0, 4)
                lbCustSearch.List(lbCustSearch.ListCount - 1, 6) = rngFind.Offset(0, 5)
                lbCustSearch.List(lbCustSearch.ListCount - 1, 7) = rngFind.Offset(0, 6)
            End If
            '   Find the next address to add
            Set rngFind = .FindNext(rngFind)
        Loop While Not rngFind Is Nothing And rngFind.Address <> strFirstFind
    End If
```

Comment: Per my test, your code works the way you want - first match is in the first row, second match in second row, etc. Maybe you can edit some sample data into the question so it is clearer what data the problem emerges from.

Comment: The issue I am finding is that if the value in B6 is a match it is found after any other records, therefore its value is shown at the end of the list.

Comment: Solved by changing the After variant to After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count)

Comment: Be careful with `.Cells.Count`. There are currently more than 16 billion cells per worksheet in Excel. If your search range is large enough, you'll run into run-time error 6 (overflow). Better to systematically use `.Cells.CountLarge` or what's in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe will typically happen if the first cell in your range corresponds to your search criteria, simply because Excel starts searching *after the search zone's top left cell*. Use

```
Set rngFind = .Find(tbCustSearch.Text, After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
```

so as to start looking after the last cell in the range. Because Find automatically wraps around, this will be your range's top left cell.